# Setting min, max for input type = number based on dropdown values in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

How to set min, max value from html only based on freqValue.

1. If freqValue = 1 then min = 1, max = 20
2. ELSE If freqValue = 2 then min = 1, max = 45
3. ELSE freqValue = 3 then min = 1, max = 100

> ```
> <input type="number" min="0" max="100" ng-model="interval" />
> <select ng-model="freqValue" ng-options="f.key as f.value for f in freq">
> </select>
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a map with those frequency values as its keys storing the `min` and `max` values for each frequency, so that when the model changed, angularjs will rebind the `min` and `max` values based on the map index, which is the `freqValue` variable.

For example:

Controller:

```
$scope.map = {
    '1': { min: 1, max: 20 },
    '2': { min: 1, max: 45 },
    '3': { min: 1, max: 100 },
};
```

Template:

```
<input type="number"
    min="{{ map[freqValue].min }}"
    max="{{ map[freqValue].max }}"
    ng-model="interval" />
<select
    ng-model="freqValue"
    ng-options="f.key as f.value for f in freq">
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```js
(function() {
  var app = angular.module('app', []);
  app.controller('main', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.freq = [{key:1},{key:2},{key:3}]

    vm.setMinMax = function() {
      if (vm.freqValue == 1) {
        vm.min = 1;
        vm.max = 20;
      }
      if (vm.freqValue == 2) {
        vm.min = 1;
        vm.max = 45;
      }
      if (vm.freqValue == 3) {
        vm.min = 1;
        vm.max = 100;
      }
    }

  }]);
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">

<body ng-controller="main as vm">

  <select ng-model="vm.freqValue" ng-options="f.key as f.key for f in vm.freq" ng-change="vm.setMinMax()">
  <option value="">select</option>
</select>
  <input type="number" ng-min="{{vm.min}}" max="{{vm.max}}" ng-model="interval" />

</body>

</html>
```